# how to stop text overlapping in nested list

Tags: html, css, html-lists, nested-lists, overlap

I have a responsive taxonomic key using dot leaders and nested ordered lists. This works great when 'a' and 'b' are nested, but when I add 'c', 'd' etc. the content becomes overlapped. The overlapping seems to occur only between 'a' and 'b', c seems not to do it and I cannot figure out why.
A picture of what I am trying to achieve can be seen [image: here]

Thanks in advance!

```css
#key {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

ol {
  list-style-position: outside;
}

ol.list {
  padding-left: 25px;
}

.list li {
  position: relative;
  list-style-position: outside;
  list-style-type: lower-alpha;
  padding-left: 5px;
  text-indent: -10px;
}

.list .list-item {
  margin: -37.3px 0px 15px;
}

.list .list-item:last-child {
  margin: 0 0 40px;
}

.list .list-item::before {
  content: ".......................................................................................";
  text-indent: 5px;
  letter-spacing: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  z-index: -10;
}

.list .list-item .text::after {
  content: "....................................................................................";
  text-indent: 5px;
  letter-spacing: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: -10;
}

.list .list-item span {
  display: inline;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding-right: 1px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.list .list-item .number {
  float: right;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #198e9d;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding-left: 11px;
}


/* Clearfix */

.list .list-item::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="key" style="text-align: justify;">
  <ol>
    <li>
      <ol class="list">
        <li class="list-item"><span class="text">This is A in the first couplet and this is fine</span><span class="number">2</span></li>
        <li class="list-item"><span class="text">This is B in the first couplet and this is fine</span><span class="number">4</span></li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li>
      <ol class="list">
        <li class="list-item"><span class="text">This is A in the second couplet and this is not fine</span> <span class="number">3</span></li>
        <li class="list-item"><span class="text">This is B in the second couplet and this is overlapping A - not fine</span> <a href="https://www.website.org/fish/thunnus-obesus/"><span class="number"><em>Thunnus obesus</em> (bigeye tuna)</span></a></li>
        <li class="list-item"><span class="text">This is C in the second couplet and although not overlapping B it doesnt have padding below</span> <a href="https://www.fishider.org/scombridae/thunnus-albacares/"><span class="number"><em>Thunnus albacares</em> (yellowfin tuna)</span></a></li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li>
      <ol class="list">
        <li class="list-item"><span class="text">This is A in the third couplet and this is not fine</span> <a href="https://www.website.org/fish/thunnus-tonggol/"><span class="number"><em>Thunnus tonggol</em> (longtail tuna)</span></a></li>
        <li class="list-item"><span class="text">This is B in the third couplet and this is overlapping A - not fine</span><a href="https://www.website.org/fish/thunnus-maccoyii/"><span class="number"><em>Thunnus orientalis</em> (Pacific bluefin tuna)</span></a></li>
        <li class="list-item"><span class="text">This is C in the third couplet and this is overlapping b - not fine </span><a href="https://www.website.org/fish/thunnus-maccoyii/"><span class="number"><em>Thunnus maccoyii</em> (southern bluefin tuna)</span></a></li>
        <li class="list-item"><span class="text">This is D in the third 'couplet' and although its not overlapping C it doesn't have padding below </span><a href="https://www.website.org/fish/thunnus-alalunga/"><span class="number"><em>Thunnus alalunga</em> (albacore tuna)</span></a></li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's due to that negative `margin-top` value for `.list .list-item`

If you set that to 0, nothing overlaps.

```css
#key {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

ol {
  list-style-position: outside;
}

ol.list {
  padding-left: 25px;
}

.list li {
  position: relative;
  list-style-position: outside;
  list-style-type: lower-alpha;
  padding-left: 5px;
  text-indent: -10px;
}

.list .list-item {
  margin: 0 0px 15px;
}

.list .list-item:last-child {
  margin: 0 0 40px;
}

.list .list-item::before {
  content: ".......................................................................................";
  text-indent: 5px;
  letter-spacing: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  z-index: -10;
}

.list .list-item .text::after {
  content: "....................................................................................";
  text-indent: 5px;
  letter-spacing: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: -10;
}

.list .list-item span {
  display: inline;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding-right: 1px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.list .list-item .number {
  float: right;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #198e9d;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding-left: 11px;
}


/* Clearfix */

.list .list-item::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="key" style="text-align: justify;">
  <ol>
    <li>
      <ol class="list">
        <li class="list-item"><span class="text">This is A in the first couplet and this is fine</span><span class="number">2</span></li>
        <li class="list-item"><span class="text">This is B in the first couplet and this is fine</span><span class="number">4</span></li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li>
      <ol class="list">
        <li class="list-item"><span class="text">This is A in the second couplet and this is not fine</span> <span class="number">3</span></li>
        <li class="list-item"><span class="text">This is B in the second couplet and this is overlapping A - not fine</span> <a href="https://www.website.org/fish/thunnus-obesus/"><span class="number"><em>Thunnus obesus</em> (bigeye tuna)</span></a></li>
        <li class="list-item"><span class="text">This is C in the second couplet and although not overlapping B it doesnt have padding below</span> <a href="https://www.fishider.org/scombridae/thunnus-albacares/"><span class="number"><em>Thunnus albacares</em> (yellowfin tuna)</span></a></li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li>
      <ol class="list">
        <li class="list-item"><span class="text">This is A in the third couplet and this is not fine</span> <a href="https://www.website.org/fish/thunnus-tonggol/"><span class="number"><em>Thunnus tonggol</em> (longtail tuna)</span></a></li>
        <li class="list-item"><span class="text">This is B in the third couplet and this is overlapping A - not fine</span><a href="https://www.website.org/fish/thunnus-maccoyii/"><span class="number"><em>Thunnus orientalis</em> (Pacific bluefin tuna)</span></a></li>
        <li class="list-item"><span class="text">This is C in the third couplet and this is overlapping b - not fine </span><a href="https://www.website.org/fish/thunnus-maccoyii/"><span class="number"><em>Thunnus maccoyii</em> (southern bluefin tuna)</span></a></li>
        <li class="list-item"><span class="text">This is D in the third 'couplet' and although its not overlapping C it doesn't have padding below </span><a href="https://www.website.org/fish/thunnus-alalunga/"><span class="number"><em>Thunnus alalunga</em> (albacore tuna)</span></a></li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, easily fixed. I should have figured that out even as a beginner! Many thanks for your speedy answer.